# Add SiteFeedweb part using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I am trying to add a SiteFeedWebPart to a SharePoint page by using CSOM. I exported the XML from a Site and then try to import into the page using the ImportWebPart .
 The XML file is as follows

```
var webPartSchemaXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
                       "<WebPart xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2'>" +
                       "<Title>Site Feed</Title>" +
                        "<FrameType>None</FrameType>" +
                       "<Description>Site Feed contains microblogging conversations on a group site.</Description>" +
                      "<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>" +
                      "<ZoneID>right</ZoneID>" +
                      "<PartOrder>0</PartOrder>" +
                      "<FrameState>Normal</FrameState>" +
                      "<Height />" +
                      "<Width />" +
                      "<AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>" +
                     "<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>" +                                        "<AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>" +                                          "<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>" +                          "<AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>" +                           "<AllowHide>true</AllowHide>" +
                        "<IsVisible>true</IsVisible>" +
                      "<DetailLink />" +
                      "<HelpLink />" +
                        "<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>" +
                       "<Dir>Default</Dir>" +
                        "<PartImageSmall />" +
                         "<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>" +
                       "<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/wp_pers.gif</PartImageLarge>" +
                    "<IsIncludedFilter />" +"<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version='16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'</Assembly>" +
"<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteFeedWebPart</TypeName>" +
                                    "</WebPart>";
```

**I get a Value not found error**

```
 var pageUrl = "Site/Pages/Home.aspx";
var zoneid = HomePageBO.LeftZone;
           var zoneIndex = 1;

           using (ClientContext context = GetContext())
           {
               var page = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
               var wpm = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
               var importedWebPart = wpm.ImportWebPart(webPartSchemaXml);

               var webPart = wpm.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, zoneid, zoneIndex);
               context.Load(webPart);
               context.ExecuteQuery();
           }
```

The error is not descriptive and does not provide information whether the XML is wrong or if there is a problem with the page or when the webpart is added.

Comment: Can you please post exact error message, line and stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I've run into something similar before when my zoneid was not right. Hope that helps!

Comment: It still comes up with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message **Value not found error** is not very descriptive. 
It can be caused by the following reasons

- Incorrect PageUrl Path
- Zone index
- Incorrect XML

To get the correct XML check if the Webpart is part of on the OOB sharepoint installed. 
Go to the [Webpart Gallery](http://~site/_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx) and download the webpart and extract the XML.

```
 var pageUrl = "/site/Pages/Home.aspx";
           var webPartSchemaXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
                                     "<WebPart xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2'>" +
                                         "<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>" +
                                         "<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteFeedWebPart</TypeName>" +
                                         "<Title>$Resources:spscore,SiteFeed_WebPart_Title;</Title>" +
                                         "<Description>$Resources:spscore,SiteFeed_WebPart_Description;</Description>" +
                                         "<FrameType>None</FrameType>" +
                                         "<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/wp_pers.gif</PartImageLarge>" +
                                     "</WebPart>";
           var zoneid = LeftZone;
           var zoneIndex = 1;
             using (ClientContext context = SiteDAL.GetContext())
             {
                 var page = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
                 var wpm = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                 var importedWebPart = wpm.ImportWebPart(webPartSchemaXml);

                 var webPart = wpm.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, zoneid, zoneIndex);
                 context.Load(webPart);
                 context.ExecuteQuery();

             }
```

Another approach to add a webpart is using the upload method shown in the [BestPractices](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Core.UploadWebPart/Core.UploadWebPartWeb/Pages/Default.aspx.cs)

Hope it helps